# how to search JSFiddle code of interest?

Tags: jsfiddle

IS there a way to search among the community for [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) specific code?

Fiddles that would have been tagged by categories, for example.

Comment: Because JsFiddle does not provide any tags to save in our fiddles we can't categories them. You can use the API of JsFiddle http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/fiddles.html though you can't get the required result But you'll definitely some thing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Go to google.com and type

```
site:jsfiddle.net <search term>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not possible per se. If you know a user's name, it seems that you can list that user's fiddles. See the [jsfiddle API](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/index.html) for an example. This one is straight from their docs -- The URL structure is:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/{username}/demo/list.json
```

And their example is http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/zalun/demo/list.json?callback=Api&sort=framework&start=5&limit=5